# Why does an empty span tag in a floated parent render on a new line?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to find out why an empty span tag would render on a new line when it's a child of a floated parent. I'm sure it's obvious but I can't find the answer.

EDIT: this is not something I'm trying to fix ... more a question for study, so I'm not really looking for a workaround as such.

EDIT: as pointed out this below this is seemingly specific to chrome

here is my code

**HTML**

```
<!-- Example 1  -->
<section>
  <div class = "parent">
    <span>contents</span>
    <span>contents</span>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- Example 2 -->
<section>
  <div class = "parent">
    <span>contents</span>
    <span>contents</span>
    <!-- empty span renders on new line -->
    <span class = "empty"></span> 
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent{
  float:right;
  background: #666;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

.parent span {
  font-size: 40px;
  background: pink;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
section {
  clear:both;
}
```

See CodePen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYGWMR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `margin-right:10px;` seems to be causing this behaviour, and only in Chrome.

FF and IE both render the span in-line.

Adding:

```
.empty { display:inline-block; }
```

seems to make Chrome behave in the same way as FF and IE.

**IMHO**, this appears to be a bug in Chrome.  Perhaps someone can shed some light on that .... Chrome v.s FF/IE, which one is right :-) ?

Comment: Thanks ... I feel you're probably right and that it's a chrome bug ... if anyone chimes in with a better idea I'll give them the tick

Answer (score 2):

Spans are designed to be embedded or wrapped i.e with a `<p>` tag. 
The span will be treated like a paragraph. I think you could add span :  inline block to get them to render inline

Comment: I didn't know that ... are spans not meant to be used as I've used them then? Also I have edited my question. I'm not trying to "fix" this, but to understand the behaviour ... note my issue is that empty tags drop to a new line whereas non empty tags render as you'd expect

Comment: To be honest. Im just looking at them as child elements of the paragraph from a Dom perspective

Comment: so there's no reason not to wrap them directly in something else other than a p tag?

Comment: Not that I can think of. You will get consistant results across all browsers handling them with p tags

Comment: Is this just in your own experience. You were saying they were actually designed to be embedded in a P tag

Comment: I believe they are. Think of how you use them or most people use them. It gives you control of every word within the paragraph. I personally would not use a div and put spans in it. I would structure it with paragraphs and if I wanted a word or a link to stand out in that paragraph I would put it in a span tag and handle it.

Comment: The example you use is not a very good one of everyday use. It may well be a bug in chrome or it is chrome expected a structure to be in place and not seeing it. Maybe the other browser just make allowances for your use above.

Comment: Usually on SO we try to keep answers factual though of course I accept your experience but yet I haven't seen any evidence that the w3c actually "designed" the span to be embedded in a p, but if you have any you should share it here it would be helpful ... to to be honest I think you're actually wrong I have never heard this myself ... even though as you say it's common to wrap in a p

Comment: It a hook in a text block which in 99% of cases is going to be surrounded by another tag other than a div. there is no purpose in doing what you doing. As a you trying to hook text that does not exist using an empty span!

Comment: Regardless of whether there is any point apparently you think it's not valid html or something ( you said spans are "designed to be embedded or wrapped" ) ... if you are right surely you can prove this? It would have to be on the w3 site I suppose but I can't find it. Generally people here are not interested in individuals' opinion.